# Matlab: How to subdivide a coarse grid system into systems with finer grids?

Tags: matlab, grid

I have a coarse grid of size say `5x5`, which I call **Grid System-1**, and I want to further subdivide that grid system in three steps as:

**Grid System-2**: Each grid of **Grid System-1** is subdivided into `5x5` with 625 total grids

**Grid System-3**: Each grid of **Grid System-2** is subdivided into `5x5` with 15625 total grids

**Grid System-4**: Each grid of **Grid System-3** is subdivided into `5x5` with 390625 total grids

In all the above steps the boundary size of all the Grid Systems is similar (say `1m X 1m`)because we are only increasing the fineness of each grid by further subdividing it. Can someone help implement this in Matlab? Thanks!

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520152/resizing-3d-matrix-image-in-matlab/12521482#12521482) to another question.

Comment: That function `resize()` from *kWave* toolbox is useful and a related google search led me to essentially similar `imresize()` function in Matlab. It would be helpful if I could change the interpolation method to some custom method.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [Coarse-to-Fine Image Reconstruction toolbox](http://nislab.ee.duke.edu/NISLab/Coarse-to-fine_estimation_%28with_software%29.html) from the guys at Duke. It may be the thing you're after.