# Three dimensional (3D) matrix interpolation in Matlab

Tags: octave, interpolation, matlab

I have a 3D matrix in Matlab of certain size, however I would need to interpolate it to obtain matrix of larger size.

```
size(M)
ans= 
  50   108    86
```

I need that matrix to be interpolated and finally obtain a matrix of size `100x213x140`. Any ideas of how to do it using `interp3`? Is this possible at all?

I've tried

```
Vq = interp3(M,1:100,1:213,1:140)
Error using griddedInterpolant/subsref
The input data has inconsistent size.

Error in interp3 (line 178)
    Vq = F(Xq,Yq,Zq);
```

If I use `meshgrid`:

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:100, 1:213, 1:140);
Vq =interp3(M,X,Y,Z);
```

Matlab seems to like it, however two things happen:

1. `size(Vq)    ans=    213  100  140`
2. I can see `NaN` values in `Vq`

The reason behind is because I need to compare two matrices sampled at different frequency. So, I could either interpolate `M` to obtain a matrix of size `100x213x140` or "reduce" the size of my other matrix `M2` of size `100x213x140` to `50x108x86`. I thought the former should be easier and safer...

Comment: Are you trying to **resize** the matrix so that it looks like the original `M` but twice as big, or do you simply want to interpolate values?

Comment: @rayryeng  I want to resize it, but I also need values for those new coordinates, hence the interpolation

Comment: I'll write a post for you now.

Comment: I had to write code for you to do so.  There is no built-in function in MATLAB.  I will modify my post.

Comment: I have written code for you.  Check my post.  Good luck!  BTW, not only is this an interpolation, this is also a resizing too.  Very good question.

Comment: To resize a 3D matrix you could also use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520152/resizing-3d-matrix-image-in-matlab/24650504#24650504

Comment: @nightlyop Can you tell me what is the difference between the method used by rayryeng here and the one explained in that thread?

Comment: @Manolete: I'm not quite sure and mybe @rayryeng can give you a better answer. I think he is doing the interpolation by hand (2d interpolation of every slice). The link i posted is how to do it directly. Maybe @rayryeng was not aware of the function `tformarray`. Also I have to admit that I just used `tformarray` without looking up how it is working exactly.

Comment: @nightlyop - You are correct.  I 2D interpolated every slice, then I used `interp1` to do a single interpolation in 3D.  I think the link that you have posted is faster and more efficient than what I did.  I wasn't aware of `tformarray` and that's a nifty function!  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Manolete - I'm still not sure what's wrong.  Perhaps you should try one of the methods in the link @nightlyop suggested.  Good luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it right.  You need to define **3D Grid** of co-ordinates.  Creating single vectors is not the right way to do it.  You can certainly use `interp3` here.  Try doing:

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:213, 1:100, 1:140);
Vq = interp3(M, X, Y, Z);
```

Note that I have swapped the row (100) and column (213) limits, as the first parameter progresses horizontally while the second parameter progresses vertically.

Also, by using `interp3` in this fashion, we are assuming that the limits of `X`, `Y` and `Z` fall within `1:213`, `1:100` and `1:140`.  Should you provide any values outside of these limits, you will get `NaN`.  There are a couple of ways you can avoid this:

1. Specify the `spline` flag at the end to allow for spline extrapolation
2. If you want to **resize** the matrix (like if you were to resize an image), then there currently is no built-in method that can resize a 3D matrix this way.  You'll have to write this yourself.

If you want to do Step #2, you can do the following.

First, you need to figure out the scale factors for each dimension.  Basically this is the ratio of the output size of each dimension with the original input size.

After this, you create a 2D grid that has its limits bounded by the original size of the input matrix, but the size of this grid will be of the size of the output matrix.  The scale factor is useful here because this effectively gives us what each value in the grid should be to interpolate.  We would create new co-ordinates that went from 1 to the output size of each dimension, in increments of `1/scaleFactor`.  As an example, if we wanted to **double** the size of our matrix, this is a factor of 2.  If we had `X` and `Y` co-ordinates that went from 1 to 3 and 1 to 3 respectively, the original grid would look like this:

```
X =            Y = 

1  2  3        1  1  1
1  2  3        2  2  2
1  2  3        3  3  3
```

To double this, this would simply be:

```
X =                         Y = 

1  1.5  2  2.5  3           1   1   1   1   1
1  1.5  2  2.5  3          1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
1  1.5  2  2.5  3           2   2   2   2   2
1  1.5  2  2.5  3          2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 
1  1.5  2  2.5  3           3   3   3   3   3
```

Note that this create an output grid of 5 x 5.  To make this doubled as 6 x 6, you can do whatever you want, but for the sake of simplicity, just duplicate the last row and last column, and so:

```
X =                         Y = 

1  1.5  2  2.5  3  3         1   1   1   1   1   1
1  1.5  2  2.5  3  3        1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
1  1.5  2  2.5  3  3         2   2   2   2   2   2
1  1.5  2  2.5  3  3        2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
1  1.5  2  2.5  3  3         3   3   3   3   3   3
1  1.5  2  2.5  3  3         3   3   3   3   3   3
```

This defines our grid of 2D columns for resizing.  Now it's a matter of resize in 3D.  What we can do is interpolate in between the **slices**.  We can easily do this using `permute` in MATLAB, and I'll show you how to do that later.  As such, the basic algorithm is this:

- Determine the output size of the output matrix you want
- Determine the scale factors in each dimension
- Create a 2D grid of interpolated access values for each dimension following the procedure above
- For each 2D slice in your matrix, use `interp2` to resize each slice to the output rows and columns using the above 2D grid.
- After, use `interp1` and `permute` to resize the third dimension.

---

Without further ado, here is the code to do this:

```
%// Specify output size of your matrix here
outputSize = [100 213 140];

%//Figure out size of original matrix
d = size(M);

%//Scaling coefficients
scaleCoeff = outputSize ./ d;

%//Indices of original slices in 3D
z = 1:d(3);

%//Output slice indices in 3D
zi=1:1/scaleCoeff(3):d(3);

%//Create gridded interpolated co-ordinates for 1 slice
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:1/scaleCoeff(2):d(2), 1:1/scaleCoeff(1):d(1));

%//We simply duplicate the last rows and last columns of the grid if
%//by doing meshgrid, we don't get exactly the output size we want
%//This is due to round off when perform 1/scaleCoeff(2) or
%//1/scaleCoeff(1).  We would be off by 1.
if size(X,1) ~= outputSize(1)
    X(end+1,:) = X(end,:);
    Y(end+1,:) = Y(end,:);
end
if size(X,2) ~= outputSize(2)
    X(:,end+1) = X(:,end);
    Y(:,end+1) = X(:,end);
end

%//For each slice...
M2D = zeros(outputSize(1), outputSize(2), d(3));
for ind = z
    %//Interpolate each slice via interp2
    M2D(:,:,ind) = interp2(M(:,:,ind), X, Y);
end

%//Now interpolate in 3D
MFinal = permute(interp1(z,permute(M2D,[3 1 2]),zi),[2 3 1]);

%//If the number of output slices don't match after we interpolate in 3D, we
%//just duplicate the last slice again
if size(MFinal,3) ~= outputSize(3)
    MFinal(:,:,end+1) = MFinal(:,:,end);
end
```

---

`MFinal` would be your final interpolated / resized 3D matrix.  The key method to interpolate in 3D is the `permute` method.  What this will do is that for each value of `z`, we will generate a 2D slice of values.  As such, if we had a slice at `z = 1` and one at `z = 2`, if we wanted to find what the 2D grid of values was at slice `z = 1.5`, this will generate a 2D slice that creates these interpolated values using information between `z = 1` and `z = 2`.  We do the first call of `permute` to do this, then another `permute` call to undo our permutation and get the original dimensions back.

Comment: That's really excellent! Should I always swap the rows and columns limits when using `interp3`?

Comment: @Manolete - Yes. The first parameter always progresses horizontally while the second parameter progresses vertically.  Also, if you want to extrapolate, use the `spline` flag at the end.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I've check the values of the matrix obtained and it seems that there are two type of values, 0s and NaNs. I have probably done something wrong

Comment: @Manolete - Don't worry.  I will fix my answer

Comment: @_rayryeng : This is an excellent explanation, thank you very much! I have followed your steps, however in MFinal I can still see some NaNs. Could I just convert those NaNs to 0s?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57416/discussion-between-manolete-and-rayryeng).

Comment: @Manolete - That shouldn't happen... I tested this on my own end and it is generating what I have expected for my tests.  Can you tell me what the nature of `M` is?  There could be a case where when `interp` is being called (1D or 3D), it could be producing `NaN`.  Maybe specify the `spline` flag for each `interp` call and see if that fixes it.  Either way, you're generating weird behaviour.  I made it specifically so that it would not have to extrapolate.

Comment: @_rayryeng : `M` represents the portion of energy in a 3D space, i.e. the energy delivered per voxel. The values range from 0 to 268435461.

Comment: @_rayryeng : I've tried using `spline` and now I cannot see any `NaN` value. Having said that, I cannot understand why `min(min(min(MFinal))) = -5.2212e+07` when `min(min(min(M))) = 0`. As you said, there is something weird here, but the matrix `M` is not really a special one it just represents a 3D space, a part of the body, with the energy dose delivered to those voxels.