# Linear interpolation inside a 3D triangle

Tags: matlab

I have data at the nodes of a 3D triangle, and I need to interpolate to get data inside the triangle.

here is what i tried to do:

```
  x=[0,1,0];
 y=[1,0,1];
 z=[0,2,-1];
 [X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(x,y,z);
 v=[2,5,-1];
 xs=linspace(0,1,.1);
 ys=linspace(0,1,.1);
 zs=linspace(-1,2,.1);
 Vs = interp3(X,Y,Z,v,xs,ys,zs,'linear');
```

i get an error: The number of input coordinate arrays does not equal the number of dimensions (NDIMS) of these arrays.

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let `X`contain the x-coordinates of your nodes, `Y` the y-coordinates, `Z` the z-coordinates of your nodes. Store the value/data at your nodes in `V`. Now you can specify where you want to interpolate the data by saving the x,y and z-coordinates of these points in `Xs`,`Ys` and `Zs`. The value of your data at these points is:

```
Vs = interp3(X,Y,Z,V,Xs,Ys,Zs,'linear');
```

You can take a look at the [Matlab documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html).

Edit: As you added your code: The error seems to be that the dimension of your `V` is wrong. If you take a look at the example Matlab Docu -> interp3 -> Evaluate Outside the Domain of X, Y, and Z you will see, that `V`has to have the dimension as `X`, `Y`and `Z`combined. From the documentation: `size(V) = [length(Y) length(X) length(Z)]` for vectors `X` ,`Y`and `Z`.

Here is an example:

```
X = linspace(-1,2,5);
Y = linspace(-1,7,23);
Z = linspace(3,9,23);
V = rand(23,5,23);

xq = linspace(0,1,34);
yq = linspace(0,2,34);
zq = linspace(4,5,34);
vq = interp3(X,Y,Z,V,xq,yq,zq,'linear',-1);
```

Comment: X Y and Z should be gridded using meshgrid? Xs Ys Zs should be vectors?

Comment: X,Y and Z can also be vectors (Matlab documentation -> interp3 -> input arguments). So X(1) is the x coordinate of your first node, X(2) of your second node,.... The same goes for Y and Z.

Comment: The same for Xs,Ys and Zs they can also be vectors.

Comment: i added my code to the question

Comment: if u can please help me to find out whats wrong in my code i will be grateful

Comment: @user2600366 I editted my answer. Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: can u please write an example for a valid v ? what does each row and column f v means? remmber that each of my original point has 1 value

Comment: Example has been added. If you look at the dimension of `vq` you'll see that every point in this example only has one value assigned.

Comment: my last issue, if i want that matrix V will have the value 1 at x=y=z=0, i should put it in v(0,0,0) and so on

Comment: I found a detailed explanation of this function here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766557/three-dimensional-3d-matrix-interpolation-in-matlab