# How to resample over one (third) dimension in matlab?

Tags: matlab, resampling

I have `double` matrix of say `480x640x128` and I want to resample it to `480x640x3`. I.e. I want each 128-element "page" portion to be interpolated and then sampled at 3 points.

How to do that?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but perhaps check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520152/resizing-3d-matrix-image-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation can be done by inserting zeros and applying Low Pass Filter.
The filter can easily be applied using the function `filter` using its `dim` property.

Now, the zeros can be done using copying the matrix to another matrix with larger 3rd dimension according to the interpolation factor.