# Resampling an image of Unequal Dimensions

Tags: matlab, resampling

I have an 3d image of dimensions(182 x 218 x 182).

How could I downsample this image in MATLAB to an image of equal dimensions (like 128 x 128 x 128)?

Comment: Did you try `interp3`? Any specific interpolation method in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
im=rand(2,3,4); %%% input image
ny=3;nx=3;nz=5; %% desired output dimensions
[y x z]=...
ndgrid(linspace(1,size(im,1),ny),...
      linspace(1,size(im,2),nx),...
      linspace(1,size(im,3),nz));
imOut=interp3(im,x,y,z);
```

I stole this answer from [resizing 3D matrix (image) in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520152/resizing-3d-matrix-image-in-matlab)